# Cleaner way of manually updating multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, coding-style

I wanted to see if there is a cleaner and more effective way of writing the SQL statement below. (MySQL)

```
UPDATE login SET is_admin=1
WHERE
memberid = 1
OR
memberid = 6
OR
memberid = 10
OR
memberid = 12
OR
memberid = 7
OR 
memberid = 3;
```

Simply want a nicer way of solving it. Optimize :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it'll be faster or more optimized, but it'll be easier to read, using [**`IN()`**](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/SQL/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_in.php) :

```
UPDATE login 
SET is_admin=1
where memberid IN (1, 6, 10, 12, 7, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine! It is only for the purpose of looking better and making it easier to read.

Comment: You're welcome :-) -- well, it's looking better ;-) *(Not sure about it, but maybe MySQL could make better use of indexes with IN than with multiple OR)*

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `IN` clause

```
UPDATE login SET is_admin=1
WHERE
memberid IN (1,6,10,12,7,3)
```